# How to constrain a generic collection to both a class name and an interface

Tags: c#, collections, generic-collections, generic-constraints

Given `public class BaseClass`

that has derived classes, where *a number of those* follow the form

`public class DerivedClass : BaseClass, ISpecificInterface`

is there a way of specifying a collection that applies to just the derived classes that implement that interface?

For example, something like

`public List<BaseClass where ISpecificInterface> myList;` or

`public List<BaseClass : ISpecificInterface> myList;`

Comment: public List<DerivedClass> myList; ? I suppose you are looking for something with more layers of inheritance, but maybe you should consider restructuring if you end up in this situation.

Comment: Not directly, but there are alternatives. What is your reasoning for wanting to constrain the list like this?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay My use case is within Unity. If the list is visible in the Editor, then you can drag items of the list type into the list and Unity will constrain you to just the specified type.

Comment: @PalleDue You said "maybe you should consider restructuring if you end up in this situation". I think I agree. Nonetheless it's good to understand this C# edge case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only constrain generic parameters, not generic arguments. So you'll need:

```
public class DerivedClassWithInterfaceListContainer<TDerived>
    where TDerived : BaseClass, ISpecificInterface
{
    public List<TDerived> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

You *may* want to inherit `List<T>` for this instead:

```
public class DerivedList<TDerived> : List<TDerived>
    where TDerived : BaseClass, ISpecificInterface
{    
}
```

And then you can use it as property type:

```
public DerivedList<SomeDerivedClass> MyList { get; set; }
```

Point being: you can only declare the list as containing one type. So if you want a list that can hold *any* class derived from `BaseClass` *and* implementing `ISpecificInterface`, you must do so in a method:

```
// either ISpecificInterface _or_ BaseClass
private List<ISpecificInterface> myList;

public void AddToList<TDerived>(TDerived toAdd)
    where TDerived : BaseClass, ISpecificInterface
{
    myList.Add(toAdd);
}
```

You could then combine this:

```
public class DerivedList : List<ISpecificInterface>    
{    
    public new void Add<TDerived>(TDerived toAdd)
        where TDerived : BaseClass, ISpecificInterface
    {
        this.Add(toAdd);
    }
}
```

But now someone can cast your DerivedList to `IList<ISpecificInterface>` and call `Add()` on that, with an object implementing `ISpecificInterface` but not inheriting from `BaseClass`.

Comment: What about `AddRange` and the indexer? What if a `BaseClass` member needs to be accessed on a list item?

Comment: It is fine (but indeed brittle) for private use if you know what you're doing and test that. It's not an ideal approach. The only solution I know of would be to have `DerivedList` implement IList<T> or ICollection<T> from scratch.

Comment: @CodeCaster To check my understanding, when you say "generic parameters, not generic arguments", that means I couldn't have something list `public class List<TDerived> myList
    where TDerived : BaseClass, ISpecificInterface;`?

Comment: @Paul yes, exactly.